# Formatter conversion - Why does the following code's result = "true"?

Tags: java, format, boolean, printf, number-formatting

When executing this code, I always get `true` as result:

```
public class TestDeclare {
public static void main(String[] args) {

double var = 34;  // any other litteral is valid
System.out.printf("%b ", var); 

}
}
```

Why I am getting `true` and not `false`? Is `true` the default value for any `Number`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See [Formatter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html):

> 'b', 'B' - If the argument arg is **null**, then the result is **"false"**. If arg is a **boolean or Boolean**, then the result is the string returned by **String.valueOf(arg)**. **Otherwise**, the result is **"true"**.

So *what is the equivalent for "false" ?* - **null** or **`false`** or **`Boolean.FALSE`**.

Comment: thx 
@OldCurmudgeon , you think the question was too bad ? i dont know why the downvote ...

Comment: Yes, thats what i said too, i was just asking for your opinion :)

Comment: @Tarik - It is possible your downvote was because it took just seconds of research on google to find the answer to your question.